# Statistical significance for ecological correlations

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

With the advent of Covid-19, attempts are springing up to look for correlations across geographical and/or political areas between the rate of infection, hospitalization, death etc. and other ecological variables.

When we are looking at the 50 states, N = 50 (51, if DC is included). An online calculator gives .28 as the minimum value of Pearson’s r for significance at the .05 level (for both N = 50 and N = 51), which I still recall from some work I did on state-level correlations about a decade ago.

At the time, I recall reading somewhere that significance levels do not apply in this case, because they have to do with inferences from a sample to a population. However, in this case there is no such inference, because the sample *is* the population.

Another interpretation is that there is such an inference, the states being a sample from a hypothetical population, so significance levels are relevant.

Which of these two interpretations is correct, or does it depend on context?

Answer (score 1):

**Description of a population.** Correlation can be a useful descriptive statistic for a population. For example, one might have data on population density and Covid-19 hospitalizations during March '20 for the 50 US states + DC. The population is the 51 US jurisdictions.

Then along with mean pop density and mean hospitalization rate, one might look at the Pearson correlation $\rho.$ No inference need be involved. The three numbers are descriptive of the population.

**Inference from a sample to a population.** With less assurance of meaningful accuracy, you might get these same numbers for a randomly chosen 15 of the 51.

Then you might wonder what CI for the correlation of the 51 you might get from data on the 15. That is inference.

**About correlation.** Many of the inferences about
Pearson's $r$ are based on the assumption that both variables are normal. This may not be the case for variables like population density and Covid-19 hospitalizations.

Then you might use bootstrapping to get an idea how
well $rho$ (population correlation) is predicted by
$r$ (correlation for a random sample of $n.$

Below is a simulated population of $n=51$ pairs $(X_i,Y_i),$ with $\rho = 0.766.$ 
One style of 95% bootstrap confidence interval
$(0.0833, 0.9226)$ for $\rho$ is computed.

```
# Simulated Population
set.seed(2020)
x = rexp(51, .01) + 100
y = x^.7 + runif(51, -30,30) + 50
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,y)
rho = cor(x,y);  rho
[1] 0.766022

# Bootstrap CI
set.seed(414)
n = 15;  B = 10^5;  r =numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
 j = sample(1:51, n, rep=T)
 r[i] = r.re = cor(x[j],y[j]) }
mean(r)
[1] 0.6858627
CI = quantile(r, c(.025,.975)); CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
0.08325656 0.92260831 
hist(r, prob=T, br = 50, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Bootstrap Dist'n of Correlation")
  abline(v = rho)
  abline(v = mean(r),col="red")
  abline(v = CI, col="red", lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The following plots show the population and the
bootstrap distribution of $r$ for samples of
size $n=15.$

[image]